# How to avoid water in a shower from appearing to fall upwards?

Tags: flash, water

If I'm photographing a bathroom shower, using flash, the fall-off of the light from the flash is such that the water droplets appear to fall upwards. That is, they appear large at the top and narrower towards the bottom of their trail. I understand that this is an optical illusion and is due to the way that the flash head emits a burst of light at full power almost instantaneously but then the light "falls away" over the following 1/1000 sec or so.

How can I avoid this? The possible effects I've seen which might work for me would be:

- a continuous stream of water
- have a flash profile such that trails of the water droplets appear to narrow towards the top
- discrete drops rather than trails

The equipment I'm using is:

- Nikon D7100
- 50 mm f/1.4 lens, though others are available
- Elinchrom D-Lite 4

Comment: Use first shutter curtain flash? Have you got examples of what you don't want?

Comment: Have you tried using lower flash power? There should be less (but still some) fall off than what you experience at full power.

Comment: @MichaelClark - The DLites are full-cycle flashes (that is, the output power depends on the capacitor charge); the flash duration gets longer as the power goes down.

Comment: It's not only an optical illusion. Water droplets do not look like the "cartoon" drops we see everywhere. Have a look at http://static.photo.net/attachments/bboard/00L/00L9fF-36529984.jpg and http://static.photo.net/attachments/bboard/00L/00L9fH-36530184.jpg from http://photo.net/nikon-camera-forum/00L9fF

Comment: @HåkonK.Olafsen It's nice to see proper evidence of what I'd heard - they make a very useful addition to this Q&A! It's why I made a point of saying "appear to" throughout my question.

Comment: @BBking No - I've deleted the only ones I'd had which showed that.

Comment: @user28116 In that case, why not try a speedlight that does have a flatter but shorter duration curve on lower power?

Comment: @ClickRick Just saw in your comment on the answer you did just that. Glad it worked!

Comment: @MichaelClark - Just to make this complete, it can sometimes take an enormous number of speedlights to do the work of one studio flash, so it's not an automatic go-to solution. At full power, the DLite 400 is "worth" roughly five or six speedlights of the SB910/580EX class (or more if you're using a large softbox, where you'd need to use a dome diffuser on each of the speedlights to fill the box properly). And if you need to keep the recycling time down as well, the speedlight numbers just keep going up. At some point, you've got to say "horses for courses" and use what you have to use.

Comment: @user28116 Why would recycle rate matter in a totally controlled environment with no human subjects? Take as long as you want, the water will keep running! And how much power do you need in the close confines of a shower? It's not like you are trying to light it from 20 feet away. As the comments on the answer below illustrate, it worked perfectly for ClickRick. We're not talking about a space here that even has room for a "large softbox". Comments on the question should be taken in the context of the unique stiuation the question addresses.

Comment: @MichaelClark - Where does it say "no human subjects" in the question? And again, it depends on what sort of lighting you're doing and what you mean by "shower". (Pro/rental studios often have something that *looks* like a shower on film but isn't in something the size of a typical domestic bathroom.) Even in a bathroom, there's plenty of room for a large soft source if you know how to construct it. Nor do you have any idea what the required aperture might be for the shot. Don't let your assumptions be your guide, think about what the problem might actually be.

Comment: @user28116 Or, alternatively, answer the question as asked, which is what you did (below). The variables which I did not include (subject, aperture, ISO, etc) were excluded simply because they remain variable.

Comment: The assumptions I made were one among several reasons why I posted a *comment* rather than an *answer*: to find out more of the specifics so assumptions could be validated or eliminated. But I'll make this assumption and stand by it: If he had access to the type of studio described in your last comment he wouldn't be here asking this question because he would have already known the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, your flashes won't be able to do the job. It's not that the DLites are altogether useless (they're really rather nice units), but the way they work — the way a lot of studio flashes work, and not just at the lower end — means that the flash duration at t 0.1 (the time when at the flash is firing at more than 10% intensity) is as short as it's ever going to get somewhere between half and full power. The lower you bring the power down, the worse it gets. Your spec sheet will show the t 0.5 going up quite a bit as you reduce power, but the t 0.1 goes up even more. It's just not a good motion freezer. (Nor are the AlienBees, Elinchrom BRX, Style and pack-and-head systems, Speedotrons, Bowens, Photoflex, Profotos other than the new B1 Air monolights,... the list goes on and on.)

Elinchrom makes one monolight, the ELC Pro HD (in two power levels) that will work. The Paul C. Buff Einsteins will do the trick at less than half the price. Most Hensels will work. The Profoto B1 Air (the new battery monolight) will work. So will the whole of the Broncolor line (like you wanted to hear that at the prices they charge).

What all of these flashes have in common is that they control flash duration by cutting off the power rather than changing the charge on the capacitor(s) — just like speedlights do (usually using IGBT devices). And that may be your real answer if you aren't going to be trying to freeze fast motion often: it can be a lot cheaper and easier to beg, borrow and/or steal a bunch of speedlights for a single shoot than to invest in a new flash system (especially when there aren't many IGBT studio units at the lower end of the price scale).

You'd probably need to double, triple, or quad up the speedlights to keep the power down and the flash duration short. And if you can narfle enough Nikon (or at least iTTL-compatible) units, you even get the option of using rear curtain sync so any remaining ambient will give you fat-at-the-bottom drops.

Comment: +1 for a lot of this content. It would have been +2 but for the Broncolor suggestion :P I shall try the iTTL direction, though, and report back.

Comment: I've been able to borrow an SB-800 today and you're right, it freezes the drops beautifully! https://www.flickr.com/groups/strobist/discuss/72157632234798676/#yui_3_11_0_3_1405182712212_322 has some numbers for the SB-800 at different power levels so I shall play with that. Rear-sync is a possibility but I'll have to play with balancing ambient light levels. And I'm now going to have to build my own modifiers for it as I had already done for the Elinchroms. Other than that, job done!